# How does Mesh based collision shapes works in Rigid Body Simulation?

Tags: mesh, physics, rigid-body-simulation, collision

I kind of understand the difference between Convex Hull and Mesh shapes. But my question is how does the physics engine works for these two? In the case of the triangles how does the engine calculate the force of colliding objects? are the contact points being calculated for each node on the mesh?

I would greatly appreciate any explanation.